# Im getting the error: register name not specified for ‘i’

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
register int i = 10;
int main(void)
{
    printf( " i = %d \n ", i );
    return 0;
}
```

Here i declared the variable i as register. But, while compiling its showing the following error

```
" error: register name not specified for ‘i’ "
```

Why we should not use register keyword in global ?

Answer (score 9):

A `register` variable is a type of local variable.
It is a hint to store the value in a register for faster access.
A register variable can not be global or static.
It can be defined only in a block.
Also please format the code you post

Comment: This interpretation of the register keyword is misleading.

Comment: @Matt Joiner:Really? Why is that?

Answer (score 5):

A `register` variable cannot be used as a "global" variable, because file scope variables have static storage, thus by definition they have an address. `register` variables are exactly the contrary, that are variables for which you, the programmer, promise to never take their address. So combining the two makes not much sense.

BTW, the error message that you get is not very helpful. It seems that your compiler is referring to an extension that allows to fix a `register` variable to a particular hardware register. If you post such an error message please also give an indication which compiler and/or platform you are using.

Answer (score 0):

The reason we should not use register keyword in global is that the life of variable defined to be of **register** storage class is within the block in which the variable is defined.

A value stored in CPU register can always be accessed faster than the one that is stored in memory. Therefore, if a variable is used at many places in a program, it is better to declare its storage class as **register**.

A good example of frequently used variables is loop counters.we can name their storage class as register.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    register int i;
    for(i=1;i<=10;i++)
        printf("%d\n",i);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -4):

Use of `register` is obsolete on most modern compilers. Don't use it.

It used to be the case that compilers were not smart enough to determine which variables would be accessed most often and therefore should be assigned a permanent place in a register. But modern compilers use techniques such as static single assignment and register allocation by colouring such that the compiler is far better than you at knowing when a variable should be in a register and when it should be "spilled" out to memory.

Furthermore, `register` places restrictions on its variable. You can't have a pointer to a `register` variable, because pointers point to memory locations, and the variable isn't in memory (at least conceptually). And a `register` variable must be an automatic variable -- commonly known as a "stack" variable. Therefore it must be a local variable within a function, and not qualified as `static` or `extern`.

In short, using `register` never provides performance gains in modern compilers, but it *does* provide programmer headaches. Premature optimization's biggest weapon -- wasting programmer time with false promises of execution time savings -- strikes again.

Comment: `register` is not obsolete at all. As you say, it poses restrictions on a variable, and this is exactly what it is designed for.

Comment: @Jens: What makes you think that's what it was designed for? Everything suggests it was designed to help 1970s and 80s era programmers write faster code by putting variables into machine registers. The lack of address is a byproduct of that, not the main goal.

Comment: @Philip: I didn't say that it *was* designed for that. But nowadays it is, and why it kept its place in all subsequent standards. Nowadays' hardware are quite complex beasts, and it is an interesting feature to be able to tag a variable as "addressless" to indicate that we want it as close as possible to the processor. Be it registers, assembler immediate, or just in cache, without having to watch for coherence.

Comment: @Jens an early draft of my answer said "Don't use `register` unless you know what you're doing.", but I thought that anyone who knew what they were doing wouldn't need the conditional. I now accept that you have raised areas where `register` is definitely useful, but you have to know what you're doing. Nevertheless, for most people, most of the time, `register` is unnecessary.

Comment: @Philip: your first phrase states much more than that, namely that it is obsolete, which it isn't. And that people have to know what they are doing when they use it is true for almost everything if they program in C. And someone coming here and asking such a specific question is definitively someone who wants to know more, such that one day he'd know what he is doing.

Comment: @Jens it's obsolete as far as its original purpose is concerned. Perhaps it's being used these days for other hijacked purposes. If the OP wants to learn about where `register` is useful, he's free to, but as you've pointed out, I'm not the expert on that, so I'm giving him my experience: it's never been needed in any of my work. If he needs to know how to use `register`, he'll find out *when* he needs to use it.

Comment: -1, Saying register is obsolete is like saying C is obsolete.

Comment: @Matt can you give an example where it is still appropriate today? I will edit my comment given new information.

Comment: The `register` keyword is still useful in embedded programming, where the programmer may be able to identify certain variables (e.g., ones shared with interrupt handlers) that can provide very high performance boosts if they're held in a reserved register.